# javascript apply on constructor, throwing "malformed formal parameter"

Tags: javascript, constructor, variadic-functions

thanks to wonderful responses to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959040/possible-to-send-javascript-varargs) I understand how to call javascript functions with varargs.

now I'm looking to use **apply with a constructor**

I found some interesting information [on this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/181348/instantiating-a-javascript-object-by-calling-prototype-constructor-apply).

but my code is throwing errors

attempt 1:

```
var mid_parser = new Parser.apply(null, mid_patterns);
```

error:

```
TypeError: Function.prototype.apply called on incompatible [object Object]
```

attempt 2:
attempt 1:

```
var mid_parser = new Parser.prototype.apply(null, mid_patterns);
```

error:

```
TypeError: Function.prototype.apply called on incompatible [object Object]
```

attempt 2:

```
function Parser()
{
    this.comparemanager = new CompareManager(arguments);
}

mid_patterns = [objA,objB,objC]
var mid_parser = new Parser();
Parser.constructor.apply(mid_parser, mid_patterns);
```

error:

```
syntax_model.js:91: SyntaxError: malformed formal parameter
```

attempt 3:

```
var mid_parser = Parser.apply(null, mid_patterns);
```

error :

```
TypeError: this.init is undefined // init is a function of Parser.prototype
```

I have a workaround for the time being:

```
function Parser()
{
    if(arguments.length) this.init.call(this,arguments); // call init only if arguments
}
Parser.prototype = {
   //...
   init: function()
   {
         this.comparemanager = new CompareManager(arguments);
   }
   //...
}

var normal parser = new Parser(objA,objB,objC);

mid_patterns = [objA,objB,objC]
var dyn_parser = new Parser();
dyn_parser.init.apply(dyn_parser, mid_patterns);
```

this works pretty well, but it's not as clean and universal as I'd like.

is it possible in javascript to call a constructor with varargs?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could use apply and pass an empty object as the `this` argument:

```
var mid_parser = {};
Parser.apply(mid_parser, mid_patterns);
```

But that solution will not take care about the prototype chain.

You could create a `Parser` object, using the `new` operator, but without passing arguments, and then use `apply` to re-run the constructor function:

```
var mid_parser = new Parser();
Parser.apply(mid_parser, mid_patterns);
```

Comment: Very interesting. I've played around with this a little and it works very nicely *in certain cases*. Not all constructors support this approach. `Date`, for example: `var date = new Date; Date.call(date, 1984, 3, 26)`.

Comment: Function.apply(new Function(),arg)
/*Is a one line solution*/

Comment: This will only work for constructors of objects you control - most constructors wont play along - there is a better way though by making a temporary constructor

Answer (score 11):

A better solution is to create a temporary constructor function, apply the prototype of the class that you want (to ensure prototype chains are preserved) and then apply the constructor manually. This prevents calling the constructor twice unnecessarily...

```
applySecond = function(){
    function tempCtor() {};
    return function(ctor, args){
        tempCtor.prototype = ctor.prototype;
        var instance = new tempCtor();
        ctor.apply(instance,args);
        return instance;
    }
}();
```

I tested the performance and found that this method is, in fact, a bit slower in the *very* simple case. However, it only takes the construction of a single Date() object in the constructor for this to be more efficient. Also, don't forget that some constructors may throw exceptions if there are no parameters passed, so this is also more correct.

My validation code:

```
var ExpensiveClass = function(arg0,arg1){
    this.arg0 = arg0;
    this.arg1 = arg1;
    this.dat = new Date();
}

var CheapClass = function(arg0,arg1){
    this.arg0 = arg0;
    this.arg1 = arg1;
}

applyFirst = function(ctor, args){
    var instance = new ctor();
    ctor.apply(instance, args);
    return instance;
}

applySecond = function(){
    function tempCtor() {};
    return function(ctor, args){
        tempCtor.prototype = ctor.prototype;
        var instance = new tempCtor();
        ctor.apply(instance,args);
        return instance;
    }
}();

console.time('first Expensive');
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    test = applyFirst(ExpensiveClass ,['arg0','arg1']);
}
console.timeEnd('first Expensive');

console.time('second Expensive');
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    test = applySecond(ExpensiveClass ,['arg0','arg1']);
}
console.timeEnd('second Expensive');

console.time('first Cheap');
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    test = applyFirst(CheapClass,['arg0','arg1']);
}
console.timeEnd('first Cheap');

console.time('second Cheap');
for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
    test = applySecond(CheapClass,['arg0','arg1']);
}
console.timeEnd('second Cheap');
```

The results:

```
first Expensive: 76ms
second Expensive: 66ms
first Cheap: 52ms
second Cheap: 52ms
```

Comment: I would quantify that its better only in the case that the "ctor" function is expensive. reason being, that this implimentation involves calling two functions as well, just that tempCtor is an empty function. The apply call to ctor (ctor.apply) would execute as a normal function, only with the new keyword would it have the overhead of constructing a new object.

Comment: I updated my post to include some tests. While it is true that with very simple constructors, this method is slower, it is trivial to make the constructor "expensive" enough to warrant this method. Also, as mentioned in my update, this improved method handles constructors that throw exceptions where arguments are not supplied or of the incorrect type.

Comment: updated my post one more time. It's now equally fast in the simple case, and even faster in the expensive case.

Comment: imho, this is a way better solution than the accepted answer. With CMSs technique you risk initializing your object twice.

Comment: One nitpicky issue: the instance you're returning is now an instance of 'tempCtor' rather than ctor. Not a huge issue in all/most cases, but users should understand that and the problems it might create.

Comment: True, sort of. Instances created by this function will still pass your typical `instanceof` tests. This is because `instanceof` uses the prototype chain and since this function links the newly constructed instances prototype up to the ctor's, everything works just fine. Try it out!

Answer (score 7):

You can exploit the fact that you can chain constructors using `apply(...)` to achieve this, although this requires the creation of a proxy class.  The `construct()` function below lets you do:

```
var f1 = construct(Foo, [2, 3]);
// which is more or less equivalent to
var f2 = new Foo(2, 3);
```

The `construct()` function:

```
function construct(klass, args) {

  function F() {
    return klass.apply(this, arguments[0]); 
  }; 

  F.prototype = klass.prototype; 

  return new F(args);

}
```

Some sample code that uses it:

```
function Foo(a, b) {
  this.a = a; this.b = b;
}

Foo.prototype.dump = function() {
  console.log("a = ", this.a);
  console.log("b = ", this.b);
};

var f = construct(Foo, [7, 9]);

f.dump();
```

Comment: This doesn't quite handle all cases.  You need to return the value from klass.apply in F(): `function F() { return klass.apply(this, arguments[0]); }`.  This handles cases where constructor functions return the value to be used as the instance.

Answer (score 0):

To complete @CMS solution and preserve the prototype chain, you can do this:

```
var mid_parser = {};
mid_parser.__proto__ = Parser.prototype;
Parser.apply(mid_parser, mid_patterns);
```

As a side note, it will not work with IE 8-.