# javascript: pass arguments to object constructor

Tags: javascript, object, arguments

i am writing a jquery lib and i need to implement Datetime functions.
i need to create a .Date() function which return a new Date object.

How to pass arguments of my .Date(args) function to Date object constructor so to create a new date object?

i tried something like this, me is the plugin namespace, me=$.jqGUI.

```
        //.Date(Value)
        /* Return a date object.
         * ReturnValue = Date(Value)
         */
        me.Date = function(Value){
            //pass arguments to Date constructor
            var sDate = Date.prototype.constructor.apply(null, arguments);

            console.log(sDate);

            //create a date object d
            var d = new Date(sDate);

            //validate date object
            if(d.toDateString()=="Invalid Date"){
                throw new Error("$.jqGUI.Date: Invalid Date");
            }
            else{
                return d;                   
            }
        };
```

here i pass to Date.prototype.constructor the arguments but i get in any case the current date.
if arguments is a date string it is ignored.
why?

Comment: `Date.prototype.constructor` is exactly equivalent to just `Date`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Instantiating a JavaScript object by calling prototype.constructor.apply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181348/instantiating-a-javascript-object-by-calling-prototype-constructor-apply)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

ok for me the following was worked

```
var args = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++)
   args.push("arguments[" + i + "]");

var d = eval("new Date(" + args.join(",") + ")");
```

Comment: I don't think you should use eval here because of its slowness. Do you really need to create your own Date function?

Comment: yes, and not only Date this would be usefull for other objects. On the other hand how slow is eval? Most people have modern machines with icore pentium and a lot of memory. I dont think such machines would have any problem.

Comment: Pass in as args: `); console.log("evil >:("`

Answer (score 7):

```
var args = Array.prototype.concat.apply([null], arguments);
return new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, args));
```

If your target browser doesn't support ECMAScript 5 Function.prototype.bind, the code won't work. It is not very likely though, see [compatibilty table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Function.prototype.bind).

Comment: Nice! But you should add a notice that this will unlikely work with any `bind` shims.

Answer (score 2):

```
Date.prototype.constructor
```

is quite useless, just use `Date` - the function *is* the constructor.

```
.apply(null, ...
```

You will need to apply a constructor on a newly created object of that type, not on `null`. See [Use of .apply() with 'new' operator. Is this possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1606797/1048572)

However, it is impossible to apply the real `Date` constructor (the function used for `new`), because EcmaScript specifies that when `Date` is called as a function it must return the current UTC time.

---

Anyway, you should not need this. Instead of receiving a bunch of arguments (of variable size), you should just specify a parameter to be a `Date` object. The user of the function can build that how *he* wants.

Your odd-looking function seems to do exactly the same as the `Date` constructor. Throw it away, and let the user apply `Date` himself - he knows which format he wants.

Also, you should not use `if(d.toDateString()=="Invalid Date")`, this is not standardisized but implementation-dependent. To check for a valid `Date` object, just use `isNaN` - the internal representation (valueof the `Date` instance) of unparsable dates is `NaN`.

Suggestion:

```
me.date = function(d) {
/* gets: a Date object or something that can be transformed to a Date
returns: a valid Date object, else throws an Error */

    d = new Date(d); // works also for Date instances, uncouples them
                     // else creates new one from string or number
    if (isNaN(d))
        throw new Error("$.jqGUI.Date: Invalid Date");
    return d;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

- **Never use `eval`**, it is dangerous.
- `bind` isn't always available and as pointed out, shims don't work the same.
- [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) also takes a variable argument list and returns a scalar that can be used by the `Date` constructor.
- `apply` only requires an array like object, not an actual array, so `arguments` is good enough.

So here is my preferred, browser safe, totally variable method.  Notice how it handles no arguments with `Date.now()`.  Passing a `null` is not the same as no arguments so that is allowed to perform the same.

```
me.Date = function(value){
    if (arguments.length < 1) value = Date.now();
    else if (arguments.length > 1) value = Date.UTC.apply(null, arguments);
    var d = new Date(value);

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The accepted answer is not ideal. I can only hope that anyone reading this thread will investigate further. Using 'eval' has a host of side-affects that I don't think you would want in a util-lib.

Here's a rough take at what you could do:

```
function dateShimmer() {  
    if(arguments.length === 1){
        return new Date(arguments[0]);
    }
    else if(arguments.length > 1){
        return dateArgumentShimmer.apply(null, arguments);
    }
    return new Date();
}

function dateArgumentShimmer(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7){
    //Direct invocation is faster than apply/call
    switch(arguments.length){
    case 2:  return new Date(a1, a2);
    case 3:  return new Date(a1, a2, a3);
    case 4:  return new Date(a1, a2, a3, a4);
    case 5:  return new Date(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5);
    case 6:  return new Date(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6);
    case 7:  return new Date(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7); 
    }
 };
```

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/y7Zmr/