# How to call Date constructor with arguments (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, date, apply

I try to apply arguments to Date, but its not work.
How I can apply arguments to native constructor Date?
I tried:

```
var a = new (Date.bind.apply(Date, ['2010-10-10']))();
```

and

```
var a = new Date();
Date.apply(a, ['2010-10-10']);
```

Comment: Perhaps you can expand on what exactly you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Felix, I tried one of those methods and its not work. You can try it youself new (Function.prototype.bind.apply(Date, ['2010-10-10']));

Comment: Check This Solution [javascript-object-by-calling-prototype-constructor-apply][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181348/instantiating-a-javascript-object-by-calling-prototype-constructor-apply

Comment: It works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/pNdHT/. Granted, your code looks pretty much the same, I cannot find the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the parameter you are using defines a specific date, just use the usual [`new Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Syntax) constructor:

```
var a = new Date( '2010-10-10' );
```

Comment: No. I need to create wrapper to Date and wrapper class can gets any params such as Date can get. Like ts, ISOString or year, month, date, etc.

Comment: @asci You should edit your question and elaborate some more on what you exactly want to achieve.